# Change Handlebars at Ghost need to restart site

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost

I'm hosting ghost via window's IIS by using IISNode.
Let's says I changed html as following, looks like I need to restart the site so the page will be update. Is there a way to not restart iis site?

```
<li class="drawer-list-item">
  <a href="{{@blog.url}}/rss/">
    <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>Subscribe to Feed
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is true only if you are running it in production mode. If this is just for dev work just run `grunt dev` and then you don't have to restart anything or run IISNode.